# MICROSOFT OFFICE 2010

Tags: ms-office, powerpoint

I have pptx file in PowerPoint 2010. When i try to open the file i recieve the following error message: Problem with the file opening
how to repair pptx?

Comment: As your question is not a developer/programming question you are probably better served if you move your question to http://superuser.com This is a forum related to end-user issues such as the one above. Also Google/Bing is your friend, try that first before posting forum questions in generic wording: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/927477

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem occurs because the PowerPoint presentation is corrupted or has been damaged.To correct this problem, try to open the PowerPoint presentation in an earlier version of PowerPoint. Or try this app - [PPTX Repair Kit](http://www.pptx.repair/)

Goos luck,
Scott